# Citrus Framework: A graphql request is giving a 400 bad request response

Tags: citrus-framework

Does anyone have an example of putting a graphql request into Citrus? I have a graphql request that works fine in Postman and JMeter for me, but I can't get it to work in Citrus. I've compared my endpoint and settings in Postman/JMeter to Citrus. In the Citrus logs the endpoint is showing up the same and my request is showing up the same as I have in Postman/JMeter.

```
From citrus-context.xml:
<citrus-http:client id="myRestAPIEndpoint" 
request-url="${endpoint}"
request-method="POST" 
content-type="application/graphql"
charset="UTF-8"
timeout="60000" />

From step definition:
designer.http()
        .client("myRestAPIEndpoint")
        .send()
        .post("/myrestapi")
        .payload(new ClassPathResource("citrus/payloads/graphqlRequest.txt"))
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}");

Here's what I’ve tried in Citrus:
Within citrus-context.xml I’ve tried both content-type="application/graphql" and content-type="application/json" (Note: In Postman and JMeter I have application/graphql)
Within citrus-context I also tried adding default-accept-header="false" (don’t think this really matters, but tried it anyway)
Within step definitions I’ve tried specifying a messageType - both .messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT) and .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
For my actual file, tried both .json and .txt extensions (I don’t think this matters since it’s purely reading in contents of the file and it’s the same either way, but tried it anyway)
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We figured this out. In Postman it has the Code link in orange (to the right of Params, Auth, Headers, Body....). This brings up a "Generate Code Snippets" window. If you click on the java snippets, it shows some java generated code samples. It basically added a {\"query\": to the beginning of it then put my graphql request in afterwards as the pair value of query. Once I updated this, my Citrus request works fine. :)